# How to run a sp from a C# code?

Tags: c#, ado.net, odbc

I am new to ADO.net. I actually created a sample database and a sample stored procedure. I am very new to this concept. I am not sure of how to make the connection to the database from a C# windows application. Please guide me with some help or sample to do the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this... (assuming you'll be passing in a Person object)

```
public int Insert(Person person)
{
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr);
conn.Open();
SqlCommand dCmd = new SqlCommand("InsertData", conn);
dCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
try
{
dCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstName", person.FirstName);
dCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastName", person.LastName);
dCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@age", person.Age);
return dCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch
{
throw;
}
finally
{
dCmd.Dispose();
conn.Close();
conn.Dispose();
}
}
```

Comment: just out of curiosity, why the empty catch block?

Comment: @DrJokepu - I deleted some of the detail before posting.

Comment: Why not use "using" instead of all the "try...catch...finally...Dispose" business?

Comment: @Luke: Not everyone has v2.0+.  He could be using 1.1.  But I, too, would prefer to see the sample show the using construct.  Or at least correctly implement the finally construct.

Comment: @Joel, I'm pretty sure that "using" has been in C# from the beginning. It's in version 1.0 of the C# spec - http://download.microsoft.com/download/a/9/e/a9e229b9-fee5-4c3e-8476-917dee385062/CSharp%20Language%20Specification%20v1.0.doc (section 8.13)

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you are looking for a tutorial on ADO.NET.

[Here is one about straight ADO.NET.](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/AdoDotNet/Lesson01.aspx)
[Here is another one about LINQ to SQL.](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/19/using-linq-to-sql-part-1.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

This is the usual pattern (it might be a bit different for different databases, Sql Server does not require you to specify the parameters in the command text, but Oracle does, and in Oracle, parameters are prefixed with : not with @)

```
using(var command = yourConnection.CreateCommand())
{
   command.CommandText = "YOUR_SP_CALL(@PAR1, @PAR2)";
   command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
   command.Parameters.Add(new OdbcParameter("@PAR1", "lol"));
   command.Parameters.Add(new OdbcParameter("@PAR2", 1337));
   command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["YourConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

        var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

        var comm = new SqlCommand("YourStoredProc", conn) { CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure };

        try
        {
            conn.Open();


            // Create variables to match up with session variables
            var CloseSchoolID = Session["sessCloseSchoolID"];


            //  SqlParameter for each parameter in the stored procedure YourStoredProc
            var prmClosedDate = new SqlParameter("@prmClosedDate", closedDate);
            var prmSchoolID = new SqlParameter("@prmSchoolID", CloseSchoolID);

            // Pass the param values to YourStoredProc
            comm.Parameters.Add(prmClosedDate);
            comm.Parameters.Add(prmSchoolID);

            comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        catch (SqlException sqlex)
        {

        }

        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
```

Comment: Why not use "using" instead of all the "try...catch...finally" business?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good starting point http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310130

```
OdbcConnection cn;
OdbcCommand cmd;
OdbcParameter prm;
OdbcDataReader dr;

try {
    //Change the connection string to use your SQL Server.
    cn = new OdbcConnection("Driver={SQL Server};Server=servername;Database=Northwind;Trusted_Connection=Yes");

    //Use ODBC call syntax.
    cmd = new OdbcCommand("{call CustOrderHist (?)}", cn);

    prm = cmd.Parameters.Add("@CustomerID", OdbcType.Char, 5);
    prm.Value = "ALFKI";

    cn.Open();

    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    //List each product.
    while (dr.Read()) 
    Console.WriteLine(dr.GetString(0));

    //Clean up.
    dr.Close();
    cn.Close();
}
catch (OdbcException o) {
    MessageBox.Show(o.Message.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If using SQL Server:

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlCOnnection("Data Source=yourserver;Initial Catalog=yourdb;user id=youruser;passowrd=yourpassword");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("StoredProcName", connection);
cmd.CommandType=StoredProcedureType.Command;
connection.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
connection.Close();
```

If not then replace Sql with Ole and change the connection string.

Comment: Why not wrap the connection in a "using" block?

Comment: I went for the simple solution to show the OP how to run a Sproc